# Inverse of Object3D.updateMatrix() in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

If I got it right: an `Object3D` has on one side the set of properties `(position, scale, rotation)` [*] and on the other side the `matrix` - this later contains esentially the same information, it's computed from the others in `Object3D.updateMatrix()` and is the one really used internally by the renderer computations. Instead, the set `(position, scale, rotation)` is  the one that is usually manipulated by the programmer (translations, rotations...).

Sometimes, however, one manipulates directly the `matrix`, and, further, instead of setting `matrixAutoUpdate=false` and forgetting about `(position, scale, rotation)`, one wants to keep the properties in sync, i.e. do what `Object3D.updateMatrix()` does but in the other direction.   Is there some implemented/efficient/recommended procedure to accomplish this?

[*] Caveats: 
1) if `useQuaternion=true`, the `quaternion` is used instead of `rotation`
2) `rotation` is complemented by `eulerOrder` 
3) I'm not sure what role play `up` in this picture, I guess it's not important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routine

```
Matrix4.decompose( position, quaternion, scale ) // revision 57dev
```

will compute the `position`, `quaternion`, and `scale` vectors from a matrix.

(In r.56 the arg names were unfortunately misnamed, and this has been fixed in r.57dev.)

If you want the `rotation` vector instead, you will have to compute it from the just-computed `quaternion` like so:

```
rotation.setEulerFromQuaternion( quaternion, eulerOrder );
```

The `up` vector is not relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks. Strange for me that the quaternion alternative is prefered. Looking at the dev branch, I'd say that `Object3D.applyMatrix()` should use that, no? I'd also suggest that that method (and others similar, that manipulate the matrix) should _optionally_ do the sync (via some flag, in the method arguments, or in the object itself). I wonder which is the place to make these kind (devel) suggestions -not exactly issues?

Comment: `Object3D.applyMatrix()` supports quaternions in dev57. And, no, your suggestion is not appropriate because it is based on a false assumption. `matrixAutoUpdate = false` is to be used when the object is static -- to save CPU cycles. It is not intended to allow the user to update the matrix in lieu of updating the `position`, `rotation`, or `scale`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `applyMatrix(matrix)` method on a 3D object. To see what it does, see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js).

Either:

1) you can feed it an identity matrix, or

2) you could copy what the function does:

```
this.scale.getScaleFromMatrix( this.matrix );
var mat = new THREE.Matrix4().extractRotation( this.matrix );
this.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix( mat, this.eulerOrder );
this.position.getPositionFromMatrix( this.matrix );
```

I'm not sure how quaternions are relevant if you do the above, I don't know the circumstances under which the useQuaternion flag is set to true. But in Object3D objects by default it's false. I have a feeling it uses quaternions only when calculating certain rotations so to avoid gimbal lock.

I think the following code taken from the `lookAt()` method would update the quaternion:

```
this.quaternion.copy( this.matrix.decompose()[ 1 ] );
```